# App content sharing if receiver has not installed app

Tags: android

Hi I would like add a feature which allows user to share appdata with friends. When the user presses the link he should be redirected to the specific entry in the app. If he hasn't got the app installed he should be redirected to the app store entry of the app. What is the best way to do this ?

Answer (score 0):

First you have to check, app is install or not in mobile. Write below code on button clicked.

```
if (isAppInstalled()){
      //Open your app}
 else{
      // open your app in playstore by passing package name
     startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, Uri.parse("market://details?id=<OUR APP PACKAGE NAME>")));}
```

Method

```
private boolean isAppInstalled() {
    boolean isAppInstalled;
    PackageManager pm = getPackageManager();
    try {
        pm.getPackageInfo("<OUR APP PACKAGE NAME>", PackageManager.GET_ACTIVITIES);
        isAppInstalled = true;
    } catch (PackageManager.NameNotFoundException e) {
        isAppInstalled = false;
    }
    return isAppInstalled;
}
```

Comment: Hi thanks for your response. But how will the user run the code if the app is not installed. I mean how is it possible to run the code using a link?

Comment: What actually you want to do?

Answer (score -1):

you may need  [deep linking](https://medium.com/@muratcanbur/intro-to-deep-linking-on-android-1b9fe9e38abd) your app

In the context of mobile apps, deep linking consists of using a uniform resource identifier (URI) that links to a specific location within a mobile app rather than simply launching the app. Deferred deep linking allows users to deep link to content even if the app is not already installed.